# Cannot display images into a table cell in PPTX using Apache POI

Tags: java, scala, playframework, apache-poi, powerpoint

I have been trying to add images into a table cell created using Apache POI within powerpoint slides, but I end up generating the error message: `The picture can't be displayed.` The table itself get's created however the error message gets insterted into the cells instead.

Here is what I have been trying:

```
    val table = slide.createTable
    for (_ <- 1 to numRows) table.addRow()
    table.setAnchor(anchor)

    for (imgList <- images) {
      imgList.zipWithIndex foreach {
        case (image, rowIndex) =>
          val tr = table.getRows.get(rowIndex)
          tr.setHeight(30)

          val cell = tr.addCell()
          val blipProps: CTBlipFillProperties = cell.getXmlObject.asInstanceOf[CTTableCell].getTcPr.addNewBlipFill()
          blipProps.setDpi(72)
          
          val ctBlip: CTBlip = blipProps.addNewBlip()
          blipProps.addNewSrcRect()

          val fillRect = blipProps.addNewStretch().addNewFillRect()
          fillRect.setL(30000)
          fillRect.setR(30000)

          val bytes = Files.readAllBytes(image.get.toPath)
          val pd = xmlSlideShow.addPicture(bytes, PictureData.PictureType.JPEG)
          println("File name: " + pd.getFileName)
          
          val rp = slide.addRelation(null, XSLFRelation.IMAGES, pd)

          ctBlip.setEmbed(rp.getRelationship.getId)

      }
    }
  }
```

Any ideas as to what I may be missing / doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495288/how-to-add-image-to-powerpoint-ppt-table-cell-using-apache-poi-hslf-xslf  It should help

Comment: @SusanMustafa - I used the example as a basis for creating my current logic - but it didn't work.

Comment: the difference that I see is in writing the picture.  You are using addPicture, vs what the answer does which is print each byte.  The answer is already using PackagePart, and you are not....if you really use the exact code from the example answer.

IF that does not work, then check the picture size? It might be too big